# Print file content from an ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, file, printing

We have files on server of several types (.pdf, .docx, .jpeg). The scenario is a user press a button (a link) and the print dialog opens which will print the content of a file chosen.
Can you please advise solutions to do it?

I think it's gonna be a link to another page where we fill in response with a file content and JavaScript window.print();

Answer (score 0):

The option you've considered (opening the file in a new page) is a good one.  You could also try doing the same thing but in an `iframe`.  That would maybe be a better user experience if you want to avoid a new page/tab opening up.